# MYSQL sort date by future dates first in ASC and old dates then in DESC

Tags: mysql, date, sorting, case

I want to sort dates in `MYSQL` in a way such that, future dates will be sorted first by in ASC order and, then then old dates last in DESC order. Here is the query I used to do, but both date types (future and old) are sorted out in ASC order. How can I fix this?

```
SELECT id, end_date FROM employee 
    ORDER BY CASE WHEN DATE(date) > DATE(NOW())
        THEN 0 
        ELSE 1 END, date ASC
```

Answer (score 3):

First, sort by the boolean expression `date <= CURRENT_DATE` so that all future dates are on the top and then sort by the absolute difference to the current date:

```
SELECT *
FROM employee 
ORDER BY date <= CURRENT_DATE,
         ABS(DATEDIFF(date, CURRENT_DATE));
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=7fd49e3d63fa6639a9f7d656f4710161).